# updating two tables from form submission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a booking form which on submission enters the booking details into a "bookings" table

But I also want to update and Events table at the same time with an adjusted figure for the sold tickets.

```
<?php
/* Duplicate information to DB */
function queryMysqli($mysql_table, $bevent_id,$bevent_price,$att1title,$att1firstname,$att1surname,$att1email, $att1phone,$people,$payment,$dietry,$message) {

    $total="60";
    $grandtotal=$total+$people;

    /* Variables */
    $error_exists = false;
    $error_mysql = "";

    /* Connection to DB */
    /* Constants, that defined in action.php, are used */
    $link = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        $error_mysql = ("Error connecting to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") ". mysqli_connect_error());
        return $error_mysql;
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

    /* Query to DB */
    /* Add data to DB */
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO ".$mysql_table."(`id`,
                                                                `bevent_id`,
                                                                `bevent_price`,
                                                                `att1title`,
                                                                `att1firstname`,
                                                                `att1surname`,
                                                                `att1email`,
                                                                `att1phone`,
                                                                `people`,
                                                                `payment`,
                                                                `dietry`,
                                                                `editor`,
                                                                `message`)
                                                    VALUES (NULL,   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $bevent_id)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $bevent_price)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $att1title)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $att1firstname)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $att1surname)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $att1email)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $att1phone)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $people)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $payment)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $dietry)."',
                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $message)."')");

    /* Get a last row ID to send in message */
    $row_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

$query="UPDATE `bookable_events` SET `sold`='$grandtotal' WHERE `bevent_id`='$bevent_id'";

    /* If error occurs */
    if (!$result){
        $error_exists = true;
        $error_mysql = "Error database query: ".mysqli_error($link);
    }


    /* Return result */
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $error_exists ? $error_mysql : $row_id;
}
?>
```

The bookings table is updating, but the events table isn't, can anyone help please?

Comment: You set a string `$query` but you don't execute that string using MySQL. You just have a string.

Comment: Thank you Bill, So I just use... UPDATE `bookable_events` SET `sold`='$grandtotal' WHERE `bevent_id`='$bevent_id'"; ?

Comment: Maybe that's correct. You don't show your table definitions so I can't be sure. My point was that setting that query to a string variable does NOT execute the query.

Comment: Also I would recommend using query parameters in your SQL queries (both the INSERT and the UPDATE). Break your habit of using concatenation and interpolation to put PHP variables into SQL queries. If you were an electrician, this is like standing in a puddle while you're working on live wires.

Comment: Argghh! I thought I had a tingle! I clearly have a lot to learn

Comment: If you're just starting out I recommend you skip `mysqli` and learn PDO instead. It's easier and faster than using mysqli. Here's a good tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I managed to get it working whoop whoop, I have no idea how I managed it but thank you for your help. I am going to look at the PDO side of things, like you suggest. At the moment I'm pinching bits of old code and guessing! which is probably not the best idea.

I appreciate your help thank you

Comment: Well, randomly pasting bits of code you don't understand is like learning to cook... if your spice rack is next to your chemistry set.

Comment: Hahah! so true! Boom! "I only wanted an Omelette!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating multiple tables in a single transaction is a common requirement. It appears that you're trying to do so with your PHP function, but there are several aspects that could be improved for better reliability, security, and readability.

Here's a revised version of your function using prepared statements and transactional queries:

```php
function queryMysqli($mysql_table, $bevent_id, $bevent_price, $att1title, $att1firstname, $att1surname, $att1email, $att1phone, $people, $payment, $dietry, $message) {
    $total = 60;
    $grandtotal = $total + $people;

    $link = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    if ($link->connect_error) {
        return "Error connecting to database: " . $link->connect_error;
    }

    $link->set_charset('utf8');

    $link->begin_transaction();

    try {
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO {$mysql_table} (bevent_id, bevent_price, att1title, att1firstname, att1surname, att1email, att1phone, people, payment, dietry, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $bevent_id, $bevent_price, $att1title, $att1firstname, $att1surname, $att1email, $att1phone, $people, $payment, $dietry, $message);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt2 = $link->prepare("UPDATE bookable_events SET sold = ? WHERE bevent_id = ?");
        $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $grandtotal, $bevent_id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->close();

        $link->commit();
        $last_inserted_id = $link->insert_id;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $link->rollback();
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $link->close();

    return $last_inserted_id;
}
```

another way that i suggest more cleaner

```php
function createDbConnection() {
    $link = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if ($link->connect_error) {
        throw new Exception("Error connecting to database: " . $link->connect_error);
    }
    $link->set_charset('utf8');
    return $link;
}

function executePreparedStatement($link, $query, $types, ...$params) {
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to prepare statement: " . $link->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to execute statement: " . $stmt->error);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

function queryMysqli($mysql_table, $bevent_id, $bevent_price, $att1title, $att1firstname, $att1surname, $att1email, $att1phone, $people, $payment, $dietry, $message) {
    $total = 60;
    $grandtotal = $total + $people;

    try {
        $link = createDbConnection();
        $link->begin_transaction();

        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO {$mysql_table} (bevent_id, bevent_price, att1title, att1firstname, att1surname, att1email, att1phone, people, payment, dietry, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        executePreparedStatement($link, $insertQuery, "sssssssssss", $bevent_id, $bevent_price, $att1title, $att1firstname, $att1surname, $att1email, $att1phone, $people, $payment, $dietry, $message);

        $updateQuery = "UPDATE bookable_events SET sold = ? WHERE bevent_id = ?";
        executePreparedStatement($link, $updateQuery, "ss", $grandtotal, $bevent_id);

        $link->commit();
        $last_inserted_id = $link->insert_id;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if (isset($link)) {
            $link->rollback();
        }
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    } finally {
        if (isset($link)) {
            $link->close();
        }
    }

    return $last_inserted_id;
}
```

hope will help you